# Predicting new data with glm step function in R

Tags: r, regression, prediction, glm

I am having trouble predicting new data with a simple step function in R. To build the model is straight forward but as soon as I invoke the predict function I get an error.

```
glm.step <- glm(medv~cut(lstat,5), data = Boston)

lstatlims=range(lstat); 
lstat.grid=seq(from=lstatlims[1],to=lstatlims[2]); 

preds1=predict(glm.step,newdata=list(lstat=lstat.grid),se=TRUE);
```

Instead of a prediction I simply get this error:

> Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : 
>     factor cut(lstat, 5) has new levels (1.69,8.93], (8.93,16.1], (16.1,23.3], (23.3,30.5], (30.5,37.8]

Comment: When you run `cut(lstat, 5)` the 5 categories are chosen automatically based on the data. When you give it new data, you get different categories because different data. Your model doesn't know what to do with the new categories---it only knows about the old categories.

Comment: You need to specify the exact breaks you want to use between the categories so that you can use the same categories on different data sets.